# Indian phone number pregmatch not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a function that gives a warning if a number other than the **+91-1234567890 format** is entered.

following code gives errors on every phone number listed below

1. +911234567890
2. +901234567890
3. 0987654321
4. 001987654321

```
    if  (preg_match('^\+?[9]{1}[1]{1}-?[789]\d{9}$')!== $_POST['billing_phone']) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>10 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
        }
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8G5HwY/1 Looks like they all fail

Comment: `preg_match('^\+?[9]{1}[1]{1}-?[789]\d{9}$')!== $_POST['billing_phone']`, syntax is also incorrect.

Comment: even ^\+?[9]{1}[1]{1}-?[0-9]{10} doesnot work

not even

function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
    $is_correct = preg_match('^\+?[9]{1}[1]{1}-?[0-9]{10}', $_POST['billing_phone']);
    if ( $_POST['billing_phone'] && !$is_correct) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>10 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match `+91-1234567890` kind of format only, just match the `+91-` followed by 10 digits strict.

```
^\+91-\d{10}$
```

Code would be like:

```
if  (preg_match('/^\+91-\d{10}$/',$_POST['billing_phone']) !== 1){
    wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>10 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks .. but I have tried following the code.. this also didn't work.

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_validate_billing_phone');
function custom_validate_billing_phone() {
   
   if  (preg_match('/^\+91-\d{10}$/',$_POST['billing_phone']) !== 1){
    wc_add_notice( __( 'The Phone field should be <strong>10 digits</strong>.' ), 'error' );
}
}


it is also showing error on right input

Comment: @BaljinderKaur What was the input that you gave?